# x264 threading latency

Tags: latency, x264

I wonder why sliceless threading (http://akuvian.org/src/x264/sliceless_threads.txt) in x264 leads to latency? If I have for example 2 threads the first encode one frame and the second encode one frame. The seconds have to wait for the first in some cases. But they can be encoded in parallel.

So two threads should be faster than only one, right?

Comment: I doubt sliceless threading was designed to decrease latency. It is not at all uncommon for multithreading to increase latency but also increase throughput. How are you measuring latency?

Comment: I haven't measured latency. One of the X264 Developer sayed that: http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/archives/249

Answer (score 3):

Frame-threading add latency in frames not in seconds because you need to feed encoder with more input frames before you start getting output frames (to fill pipeline). Encoding one frame itself will take about near same processor time as with one thread but threading allow pipeline process by encoding **different frames parallel**. From other hand sliced-threading decrease latency because all threads encode **one frame parallel** so it would be finished faster than encoding it with one thread (also sliced-threading don't need latency in frames for pipepining).

Comment: Thank you so much!

In summary: sliceless or frame-based threading leads to lateny, because the whole pipeline has to be filled. For example with 5 threads the encoding process starts if all 5 threads have one thread. Correct?

Sliced-threading decrease latency, because the frame is splitted into slices. The slices are then encoded parallel. If the first frame is finished the second will be encoded. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

It took me quite a while to reason through it, but the answer is Queuing Theory.

Each frame can be started when half of the previous frame has been encoded. But if parallelization is going to provide any benefit most (preferably all) threads should have a frame to work on. 5 threads means 5 frames. That is the pipeline. Any time the pipeline is not completely full, parallelization is giving you less of a benefit. If the pipeline contains only one frame, only one thread is working and therefore you get no benefit from parallelization. But if your pipeline is usually full, what is it full of? Unencoded frames. Unencoded frames are frames that must have been captured and therefore they represent that many frames worth of latency. The latency might be slightly less by a small constant portion of a frame because some of those frames in the pipeline are partially encoded but in general each item in the pipeline contributes to the latency.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for added latency with more threads is that the consecutive frames use each other for motion prediction and compensation. That means in order to compress a frame you need info from previous motion estimation details. That means the frames are dependant on each other and sometimes they have to wait for at least some data from other threads as well. This is in contrast with the slice threading when threads slicing up the frame and each one works on one slice and all on the same frame and they have all the needed info from previous frames, or next in case of B frames.